# How to fix Spring4Shell Remote Code Execution Vulnerability (CVE-2022-22965) on System-Jfrog-Artifactory nodes

Tags: spring, artifactory, spring4shell

What is the correct way to solve this vulnerability? Should we upgrade version spring shell version to 5.2.20

I am using Spring Boot directly – upgrade to version 2.6.6

Answer (score 0):

JFrog platform is not vulnerable to SpringShell CVE-2022-22965.

JFrog's Security Research team investigated and detailed their findings and remediation strategies in this blog, and introducing a new set of OSS tools to help developers address this latest threat.

The documents from JFrog, below should help you on this issue and remediation
https://jfrog.com/blog/springshell-zero-day-vulnerability-all-you-need-to-know/
https://jfrog.com/blog/springshell-remediation-cookbook/

Comment: here i am using jfrog artifactory as a container with the version 7.18.12 and now i have found this vulnerability in the artifactory . Can someone to suggest to which version of jfrog artifactory image should i use such that i can get rid of this vulnerability  .